# redirect username to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

i need to a script that it can do it

```
blogname.domain.com = > http://www.domain.com/blogname/
```

i think it possible with .htaccess file but i dont know it, so help me

thanks alot

Comment: what CMS are you using? Wordpress?

Comment: Look up mod_rewrite. Match on the hostname, extract the blogname, rewrite to the other format.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess you can do the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com(.*)    http://www.domain.com/$1$2
```

This rewrites http://username.domain.com/anypath
internally to http://www.domain.com/username/anypath